# CRIME - attack TLS compression

Tags: tls, compression

In the CRIME attack slides at the Ekoparty presentation (where it was first introduced), I didn't get something.
In slides 32-35 ( https://www.ekoparty.org/archive/2012/CRIME_ekoparty2012.pdf )
When we attack TLS compression - as is, why do we need to use the "Chosen Boundary Attack" concept?
Why do we need to fill 16k of data, split it to 2 records and leave the last byte (time after time) to get each byte?
We can put out guessed secret to the url when the whole secret is in the first record without filling the 16k record, why wouldn't this work?
Thanks!